# Change behavior of launching Android app from "recents" and from the launcher

Tags: android

How can I get my application to resume in the same way (from either the launcher or from "recents") after I minimize it?  (In Android, resuming from the launcher or from "recents" is not the same action.)  Are there any flags or launchModes, or anything else I need to do that will cause my application to resume its previous state regardless of where it's started?

An example:

```
Activity A (normalMode) -> 
Activity B (singleTask) -> 
Activity C (normalMode) -> 
Activity D (starts from service with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and 
            FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and intent(getBaseContext(), ActivityD.class))
```

The first time I minimize `Activity D`, it resumes on `Activity D` from either "recents" or from the launcher, which is what I want.

But after that, if I start `Activity B` (with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`) from `Activity D`, `Activity C` and `Activity D` are destroyed, which is fine.

But if I repeat and do this again, then `Activity D` is shown again. If I minimize `Activity D` and resume from launcher, `Activity D` starts, which is ok. However, if I minimize and resume from "recents", I see `Activity B` and `Activities C` and `D` are destroyed immediately.

That's not what I want. Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Thanks for answers :-)

Comment: You better try to describe with less words.

Comment: If i describe the less words, you do not understand and will say "use the search". Title of my post is tell you what i want. Body of my post is explaining my problem.

Comment: ,..you see, You didn't get an answer in an hour.the reason is your description. Please help people to help you.

Comment: I already did it. I describe all the activities and their switches. And told whats the concrete problem. I started to think, that i didnt get an answer because there is no answer on this queston...

Comment: I just called finish() on all previous activity, before Activity D. And all resuming works as expect. But i need activity B (singleTask) and do not want destroy it...

Comment: I don't know much about Android development, but I tried editing your question to make your meaning more clear.  Feel free to roll it back if you think I misrepresented anything.